# WSL Bash doesn't start

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1709

I have been using Windows 10's **Windows Subsystem for Linux** `bash` (Ubuntu via Microsoft Store) in the last few weeks, no problem, awesome feature, couldn't be happier.

But today it suddenly stopped working. Typing `bash` just does nothing on the command line (`cmd` and PowerShell), as if it would be waiting for something. It doesn't crash or output an error message, but just keeps showing a blinking cursor.

[image]

(Cursor not visible on screenshot, it is a blinking `_` on the next line after `bash`)

Task manager shows both command lines at 0% CPU with a "Microsoft Bash Launcher" process also at 0% CPU:

[image]

Any idea how to debug and fix this?

Update: After a few manual restarts and one "crash" (I think `explorer.exe` stopped, and didn't really come back after killing the process after a prompt) it now works again for now.
I had the problem a few weeks before (where I fixed it be reinstalling WSL), so I assume it will reappear sooner or later.

Comment: I would uninstall and reinstall `WSL Ubuntu`, I normally would suggest you reset it, but that requires a working instance.

Comment: Some really smart folks seems to have found a solution to the problem. Check out the [solution here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/849#issuecomment-252053937).

Comment: In order to uninstall the WSL you have to use [wsl-config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config)

Comment: Is `wsl.exe` working?

Comment: @Biswa No, exact same behaviour for `wsl.exe` and `ubuntu`. Also when running PowerShwell or `cmd` as Administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the link to `wsl-config`, but I want to avoid re-installation if possible. Get a working setup was not easy, and to be honest I have no idea how to recreate it. Will take better notes if I really find no other solution though.

Comment: So did you attempt the pagefile solution.  If you didn’t then you are out of options.

Comment: "Unfortunately" (I am actually pretty happy about it for now...) after a few manual restarts and one "crash" it now works again for now. I had the problem a few weeks before (where I fixed it be reinstalling WSL), so I assume it will reappear sooner or later.

Comment: Do you have [detailed logs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#8-detailed-logs) we can review?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049070/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-not-starting

Comment: @EyalRoth: Indeed ... although this seems the more appropriate site.

Answer (score 56):

Try to do a full reboot of Windows10, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and click “Restart.”

Normal reboot/shutdown action in the start menu will not shutdown Windows 10 fully, for the “fast boot” mechanism saves memory from the last session. The other answer mentioned changing system settings which make Windows 10 doing a full reboot, it works, but unnecessary.

By holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click the “Restart” in the start menu, Windows 10  will go into advanced restart mode, choose “Shutdown” from the menu. Then start normally again.

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't have to change any settings, and this worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. I wish they fix this though

Comment: I got into maintain mode and clicked the special shutdown button, but when I booted back up bash still wouldn't start.

Comment: Sure, reboot every time it gets stuck. Classic windows xD

Comment: It works, but the problem will happen again eventually

Comment: Thank You! It worked! Posted this issue on GH:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5503

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: Advance restart menu?

Comment: Nope. As it turns out, rebooting doesn't fix every problem :)

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

As discussed on https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/849 by user [imkimchi](https://github.com/imkimchi) the steps for solving this issue are:

> 1. Run windows + R
> 2. type SystemPropertiesAdvanced
> 3. click settings in performance group
> 4. In advanced tab, click Change under Virtual Memory and deselect the automatically manage paging file size for all drives
> 5. Select custom size and enter 800 for initial size, 1024 for maximum size.
> 6. Apply changes and restart.

Comment: This is not a complete solution. I suspect changing the page file management itself causes WSL to start working again. Mine got stuck, and I got it working after reading this answer, but then after a month or so, it got stuck again. I reverted my virtual memory to "System Managed", and WSL started working again. I don't know what to make of it :-|

Comment: When I went to this window I already had almost 32gb of RAM allocated... so I think this is not the solution.

Comment: When I restart my PC, my WSL instance usually starts working again without having to change this. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯