# WSL Ubuntu bash: The operation timed out because a response was not received from the virtual machine or container

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 10.0.21337 (windows insider program) and installed WSL with Ubuntu and Windows Terminal. After a firmware update the ubuntu bash wouldn't start anymore. In a cmd.exe the response was:

```
The operation timed out because a response was not received from the virtual machine or container.
```

I found this message in a few pages on the www but they were mostly related to docker containers.

Answer (score 30):

A faster solution than a full PC restart is to run:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

...which will restart just the WSL service.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly.

Comment: This also solved my timeout issues that appeared after a Windows 11 upgrade.

Comment: This does not work for me.. but I've got a long running process that is using just over a third of the CPU which makes it seem like WSL won't initialize if the system is busy enough.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1275505/wsl-bash-doesnt-start) is a bit different in terms of the symptoms but its solution solved this problem:
A full reboot of Windows10, by opening Windows > Start Menu > Power > Restart while holding the shift key.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the issue by performing the following steps:

1. Uninstall WSL2
2. Enable Virtual Machine Platform:

   > Open PowerShell as Administrator and run: 
   > `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`
3. Enable Hyper-V:

   - Go to `Windows settings` and search for `Turn windows feature on / off`
   - Check/select `Windows Hypervisor Platform` and `Windows Machine Platform`
4. Restart the machine to implement the changes.
5. Download the following Linux kernel update package and install

> https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi