# WSL doesn't want to launch

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have just installed WSL 2 but I have difficulties to launch it.

**My installation**

I did the official installation from Microsoft. Manual installation, I chose "Ubuntu" in the Microsoft Store and it installed Ubuntu 20.04 : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

I have a Dell Inspiron 5593, processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU. I am on Windows 10, version 2004, build 19041.1083.

**The issues**

- When I execute `wsl` or `wsl.exe` in the command prompt or power shell, nothing happens.
- When I search "wsl" in the taskbar and click on the icon, a Linux terminal appears and disappears quickly.
- After I followed the previous points, `wsl.exe --list --all --verbose` in the power shell gives me :

  ```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  Ubuntu                 Stopped         2
  ```

(with a * before "docker-desktop-data")

- The only way I have found to launch it is to go to the Microsoft Store, find Ubuntu and click on the "launch" button. Then a terminal opens and I can execute Linux commands without other issue.
- When I try to execute WSL commands (except `wsl.exe --list --all --verbose`) on command prompt or power shell it says my command is invalid and prints the usage informations.

**What I tried to solve the problem**

- Execute `sudo apt get-update` on a Linux terminal.
- Open the Windows settings, clicked "check for updates" and I don't have any update to do.
- Make sure "Windows sub system for Linux" is enabled in Windows settings.
- Read the following links :

"Troubleshooting installation" section at the end of the installation page : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting

- And other old links, apparently trying to solve an elder bug from august/september 2020 :

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5836

[WSL Bash doesn't start](https://superuser.com/questions/1275505/wsl-bash-doesnt-start) and tried the two answers

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5912

- Link in french : https://www.ionos.fr/digitalguide/serveur/know-how/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/
- Reboot my computer everytime I tried a solution

Comment: Look in Programs and Features, Windows Features, and ensure WSL is enabled (down at near the bottom of the list).

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling the WSL instances?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be wrong/no default distribution. Try setting the default distribution:

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
```

If that fails, try unregistering and reinstalling the distribution.

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu
```

then go to the Microsoft store and click **Launch**.

Comment: "wsl --set-default Ubuntu" worked ! Thank you.
Is it normal that wsl launches in the Windows command prompt ? When I click on "launch" in the Microsoft Store, it is different : it opens a Linux terminal with the Ubuntu icon.

Comment: Unless something's change in the Store installation of Ubuntu recently, it *should* be the same underlying terminal app ("Windows Console") either way, just with a different icon.  Click on the icon for both -- Do the menus look the same?  Anyway, my recommendation is to install Windows Terminal, Microsoft's newer, open-sourced, much more-feature reach "replacement" (at some point).  It can be installed from the Store as well.  It has auto-detection for WSL installations, so it will create a menu entry for each in the event you install more than one.

Comment: `wsl -l` will list available images, thank you, it helped me to fix the issue I was facing.